# Attempted import error: 'styles' is not exported from './styles.scss' (imported as 'styles')

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-modules

guys

I'm trying to build my react project, but it keeps saying

`'Attempted import error: 'styles' is not exported from './styles.module.scss' (imported as 'styles').'`

So, I guess I've got wrong settings in my webpack config file but have no idea what's wrong in there. I'm using css module so have tried this way https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/#css-modules-are-imported-as-es-modules, but didn't work for me.

This is the one of the source file I'm using styles

```
import styles from "./styles.scss";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const ArrowBack = ({ history, onClick }) => {
    return (
        <button type="button" onClick={onClick || history.goBack} className={styles.arrowBack}>
            <span className={styles.bar}></span>
        </button>
    );
};

export default withRouter(ArrowBack);
```

Here is my files

- webpack config
  https://gist.github.com/bbatta38/45695862bdde7928b788420793c006b6
- package json
  https://gist.github.com/bbatta38/4b91a2b84aaa237b54277b78525f8473
- build js
  https://gist.github.com/bbatta38/e18792375a107afcfedfeba48bc3fe1e

It's been already two days to find out any ways to make it work. Please help me if you have any idea to resolve this error.

Comment: The error mentions './styles.module.scss' but in your code you're importing  "./styles.scss"

Things you can try:
- Importing a css file the same way as your scss file (it looks like you have sass-loader imported and installed so I don't think it will make a difference)
- Making sure your sass module is named .module.scss and imported as such in the JS file
- Make sure you're importing as the default "import styles" and not as a named export "import {styles}"
- read the documentation for CSS modules in a React app: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: Thank you so much, You saved my day. I didn't notice I wrote it '.module.' one of the files and all styles' file is just 'styles.scss'. I thought it must be something in webpack config file, because I was upgrading webpack and react etc's versions and so I reckon this error came from versions conflicted. thanks again, it built well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
```

It seems you're missing the 'module' in the file name.

Comment: Thanks I found the bug from your comment above.

Comment: Great @bbatta, you can accept this as the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

since Gatsby v3 you need to import the style like this:

```
import * as styles from './styles.module.scss'
```

Comment: could you share your gatsby ocnfig file?

Comment: sorry I'm not using Gatsby

Comment: So why you're providing the gatsby documentation https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/#css-modules-are-imported-as-es-modules

Comment: do you have a link of your project in github?

Comment: Just let you guys know I tried everything I could, sorry for confusing. and the project is private, you may not able to see it, this is company one.

Comment: If you can't share the repo could you create a sample with just the config files and the css and js file to recreate the issue?

Comment: @KadyT. Thanks mate for trying to help me. the bug found, explained above. just typo 

Comment: ur welcome @bbatta. keep coding 